# Android NFC foreground dispath error to two instance of same activity

Tags: android, nfc

I had made the application which was using NFC to read card in Android. The application get NFC tag data by using NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch() method in ReadActivity, and it work well except one case.

here is the flow of case:

1. start the ReadActivity(firstly instance)
2. back to home
3. launch a third App who calls ReadActivity by intent ;
4. read card by the secondly ReadActivity
5. something strange happend !! the firstly ReadActivity instance was
   brought to front and got the nfc data !

here is the partly code:

***I: ReadActivity***

```
package com.song.nfctest;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcB;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class ReadActivity extends Activity {
    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        setContentView(textView);

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        resolveIntent(getIntent());

        if (getCallingActivity() == null){
            textView.append("\ncalled by self");
        }else {
            textView.append("\ncalled by other app");
        }

        textView.append("\n\n\n\n\n\ntap your nfc tag to phone to continue ");
    }
    void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        printLog("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Parcelable p = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (p == null) {
            return;
        }
        Tag nfcTag = (Tag) p;
        final NfcB nfcb = NfcB.get(nfcTag);
        try {
            nfcb.connect();
            printLog("----------- complete with  read logic----- ");
            textView.append("\n\n\n\n\n\n get nfc event !!!");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                nfcb.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdapter == null) return;
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0),
                new IntentFilter[]{new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)},
                new String[][]{new String[]{NfcB.class.getName()}});
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAdapter == null) return;
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
    void printLog(String message) {
        Log.e("krik", message);
    }
}
```

***II: clientActivity:***

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("call main app");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callApp();
            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(button);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }

    private void callApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.song.nfctest", "com.song.nfctest.ReadActivity"));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
}
}
```

**PS1: I had guessed it caused by  requestCode of pendingIntent, I had changed it but it not worked finally.**

**PS2: I got a very simple demo and upload to github: https://github.com/songsyl1207/nfctest.git .run app module and otherapp module to the android device, then operate as the question flow ,you will see it.**

hope somebody can help me !

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you. And instead of a screenshot of an image, please use [code indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Actual text is easier to read, can be copied and can be read by search engines.

Comment: thanks for your reply very much !! it is the first time that i ask question on stackoverflow ....it seems that i had done something stupid ,haha.I simplify the huge project to a simple demo and upload to github .

here is the repository url: https://github.com/songsyl1207/nfctest.git 

hope your next reply!